# CakePHP 2 Validation error with jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, cakephp, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have a form with a jQuery autocomplete using the standard approach with a visible input field for the text and a hidden ID field for the - yes - the id to pass. To avoid invalid inputs I check the id with CakePHP validation. The standard implementation would show the error message on the hidden id field, ie. it wouldn't show up at all. Now I implemented two ways to redirect the error message to the visible input field:
1) I set the validation rules for the input field and not the hidden id field. Validation takes place in a custom function where I use $this-data['id'] to check the validity of the id.
2) I've added an additional key 'redirectMessage' to the validate array and in the ModelValidator class, I've modified the method 'invalidate' like:

```
$curVal = $this->_model->validate[$field];
if(array_key_exists('redirectMessage', $curVal))
    $field = $curVal['redirectMessage'];

    $this->getModel()->validationErrors[$field][] = $message;
```

Both ways work as expected - but - isn't there an official way to solve this problem?

Regards

Alex

Answer (score 0):

[Model::invalidate()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Model.html#_invalidate) might be an "official" way to do this?

```
$this->getModel()->invalidate($field);
```